# What are UIPageViewController#initWithTransitionStyle options keys?

Tags: rubymotion

The [rubymotion docs](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/UIPageViewController.html#initWithTransitionStyle%3anavigationOrientation%3aoptions%3a-instance_method) say:

> options (Hash) — A dictionary of options. For keys, see “Options
>   Keys.”

But where? See where?

There are keys in original [ios docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html), but what is the rubymotion analogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys will be the same as from the iOS docs you reference

```
UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey
UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey
```

> **`UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey`**
>     Location of the spine.
>   For possible values, see “[Spine Locations.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)” A spine location is only valid if the transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`.
>   If the transition style is `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`, the default value for this property is `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin` otherwise, the default is UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationNone.
>
> **`UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey`**
>   Space between pages, in points.
>   The value should be a CGFloat wrapped in an instance of NSNumber. The default value is zero. An inter-page spacing is only valid if the transition style is 
>   `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.

If your question was regarding the docs that's probably an issue to be raised with the maintainers as other constants have pages e.g. [UIInterfaceOrientation](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/UIInterfaceOrientation.html)

Comment: Thanks! I tried same keys (for location) but they were ignored. But then I tried them again now and they work. Must have confused myself somehow.